# Call a single cell from a .CSV using PHP

Tags: php, excel, csv, import

I've a problem to import a single cell in csv,
i have a csv file that contain 7 column and ~1420 row,
i need to read only the 4 column number in 1420's row, how can i do it?

```
         <?php
         $url = "wp-admin/ftp/test.csv";
         $csvData = file_get_contents($url);
         $lines = explode("\n", $csvData);
         $array = array();
         foreach ($lines as $line) {
             $array[] = str_getcsv($line);
         }
         echo $array[1];
         ?>
```

with this i have an array to output with all cell in one row, 
but i need to take the third number in that row, and not all of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe $array is multidimensional the following should print what you want:

```
echo $array[1419][3];
```

Otherwise you can print it to check how it is structured:

```
print_r($array);
```

UPDATE: unidimensional

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $array[] = str_getcsv($line)[3];//PHP 5.4
}
echo $array[1419];
```

Comment: And can i take only the first 4 number of that cell?

Comment: The last update give me an error unexpected in the 2nd line in -->  [3] ,